# Shall we migrate our WPF application to UWP app now?

Tags: wpf, win-universal-app, uwp

Our company has a WPF application for displaying business data, we used **Telerik Chart control**, it's perfect. We are considering if this is the right time to migrate our app to the new [Windows 10 Universal app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn894631.aspx), it looks powerful. Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: What exactly is your question? The Telerik chart control is also in Telerik's UI controls for UWP apps, which was released 1 or 2 weeks ago. You could also check WinRT XAML Toolkit, which was released some days ago, and port it, if it's not worth the money. Depending on what platforms you want to reach (especially Mobile or let's say ARM in general is not possible to develop for using WPF) and have the money, porting does make perfect sense.

Comment: Thank you for your information, I will check that, looks like we are outdated...

Comment: It depends on what you need, Microsoft will allow you to host your wpf app in the store at some point next year.

Comment: Thank you, guys, appreciate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends, if your company/clients are adopting Windows 10 already it might be worth doing. But if you have customers running Windows 7 or 8 it might take a while for them to migrate.

Probably, as a first step you might want to use portable libraries as much as possible, so you can reuse most of your View Model, Models, DTOs and business logic across different platforms (full .NET and WPF, Windows Runtime and UWP).

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion~